# why converting list to set doesn't work in my notebook and lab but same code in other notebook works?

Tags: python, duplicates, set

I am trying to remove duplicates from list by converting it to set but for a code it shows me

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
1 list1= [12,43,56,12,64,35,6,3,12,56,43]
2 print(list1)
----> 3 abx = list(set(list1))
4 abx

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

But same code in other tab works fine why is it happening?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFZP7.png)

Comment: You are probably have a variable named list, that is shadowing the built-in

Comment: I bet you have redefined keyword `list`.

Comment: This code works fine. You would have assigned some object to list earlier and overwritten the list function with an object

Answer (score 0):

So basically you are redeclearing a list as a list and then passing that to the set method you want to have it like this

```
your_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
your_set = set(your_list)
```